# DirectCompute CreateBuffer fails with error 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)

Tags: c++, directx, directcompute

I'm trying to create a buffer in GPU memory to upload data from CPU. GPU access will be readonly. Data will be used as an input buffer for a compute shader.

CreateBuffer() fails with error 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG). I read the docs and read it again without discovering which argument cause the failure.

Here is an extract from my code where I marked the failure:

```
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect( g_hWnd, &rc );
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
    {
#ifdef WARP
      D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
#else
      D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,        
#endif
    };
    UINT numDriverTypes = sizeof( driverTypes ) / sizeof( driverTypes[0] );

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory( &sd, sizeof( sd ) );
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT | DXGI_USAGE_UNORDERED_ACCESS | DXGI_USAGE_SHADER_INPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = g_hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;


    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevels =   D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

    for( UINT driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex++ )
    {
        g_driverType = driverTypes[driverTypeIndex];
        hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( NULL, g_driverType, NULL, createDeviceFlags, &FeatureLevels,1,
                                            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &g_pSwapChain, &g_pd3dDevice, NULL, &g_pImmediateContext );
        if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
            break;
    }
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;


    // check if GPU supports doubles
    D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_DOUBLES fdDoubleSupport;
    g_pd3dDevice->CheckFeatureSupport( D3D11_FEATURE_DOUBLES, &fdDoubleSupport, sizeof(fdDoubleSupport) );
    GPUcanDoDoubles = fdDoubleSupport.DoublePrecisionFloatShaderOps;


    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc;
    BYTE Data[200];
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    desc.BindFlags           = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc.Usage               = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags      = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    desc.ByteWidth           = 200;
    desc.MiscFlags           = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
    desc.StructureByteStride = 2;
    InitData.pSysMem = Data;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&desc, &InitData, &g_pcbFractal);    // <== E_INVALIARG here

    // Create constant buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC Desc;
    Desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    Desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    Desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    Desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    Desc.ByteWidth = ((( (GPUcanDoDoubles) ? sizeof(MandelConstantsDoubles) : sizeof(MandelConstantsNoDoubles) ) + 15)/16)*16; // must be multiple of 16 bytes
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &Desc, NULL, &g_pcbFractal);        // This one succeed
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: (a) Turn on the Direct3D Debug Device and look for output. (b) Always check the HRESULT of all functions that return it. It's only safe to ignore ``void`` return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling [Direct3D 11 Device Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-layers) and looking at the debug output window answers your question:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer: When creating a buffer with the MiscFlag D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED specified, the StructureByteStride must be greater than zero, no greater than 2048, and a multiple of 4. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #2097339: CREATEBUFFER_INVALIDSTRUCTURESTRIDE]

If you fix that, you get:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer: A D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC Resource cannot be bound to certain parts of the graphics pipeline, but must have at least one BindFlags bit set. The BindFlags bits (0x88) have the following settings: D3D11_BIND_STREAM_OUTPUT (0), D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET (0), D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL (0), D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS (1). [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #64: CREATEBUFFER_INVALIDBINDFLAGS]

Which is basically telling you that you can't combine `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` with `D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS`